# Slide up function does not work

Tags: jquery

I have checkboxes like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1500-374-Breckin Meyer" id="artistBreckin Meyer" class="ImdbAddArtist" name="artist[]">
```

```javascript
var exploded = value.split('-');
$("#" + par2 + "").append(('<br /><input type="checkbox" name =' + par + ' value=' + exploded[0] + "-" + exploded[1] + '-' + exploded[2] + ' />' + exploded[3] + '<br />'));
$('#artist' + exploded[3]).slideUp('slow');
```

It adds my div but the following line doesn't work:

```
$('#artist' + exploded[3]).slideUp('slow');
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: where does the script live? What is 'par2'? How do you get 'value'? Why do you add empty quotes after 'par2'
?

Comment: You should work on your accept-rate. Start accepting more answers, or else you won't receive many answers.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the character `-` as a split separator, and the string you are splitting is `1500-374-Breckin Meyer`. Given your code, this would produce an array of the strings `1500`, `374` and `Breckin Mayer`.

In other words, you have 3 elements (index 0 to index 2) in the resulting array of strings/segments.

However, as shown below you are referring to a fourth segment (index 3).

`exploded[3]`

Comment: is it possible to slide up checked checkbox ? Can i do that  with checkbox class *

Comment: I would generally make a separate question for this, but  the :checked selector will help you (http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector). If my answer helped to the original question, mark it as answer.